# Links stopped working for logged in admin user

Tags: navigation, javascript

Please help me with this urgent problem:
after some modifications all links on my site stopped working. I can hover them and see the url, but on click nothing happens. No WSOD, no error page, just no action at all. As if the link behaviour is gone. When I log out by typing .../user/logout in the adress bar, all links work as normal.

System: drupal 7 with open atrium latest version

Modifications I made just before the problem started:
- installed colorbox library
- added sites/default/files/* in colorbox>advanced>exclude pages (why? because I could'nt get colorbox working and some site mentioned to do this, can't find back the link)
- cleared cache

Problem is: I can navigate to /admin/config/media/colorbox, I can delete 'sites/default/files/*' from the excluded pages, but I can NOT submit the form so the changes take effect, because links don't work.

Please help, I've googled every possible search combination, but no result...

What else could have caused this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The only things that could cause that are 1. A problem with the browser (unrelated to the website), or 2. Javascript. I don't want to cause alarm, but the fact that you suddenly can't perform any administration tasks might suggest you've succumbed to the [recently announced security vulnerability](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005). Try disabling javascript in your browser to see if you can submit the form (you almost certainly will be able to), and try to get someone to look at your db/files even if that fixes it, just to be sure. And then update core ASAP :)

Comment: Clive, thanks a lot for your quick response. I disabled javascript, and indeed links work again! When I re-enable javascript again, links return dead. I already updated the open atrium distribution to close the security vulnerability three days ago, so I don't think someone else messed up the site. It probably was me ...

Comment: With javascript disabled, I reset all colorbox and jquery settings to default, then deleted the colorbox library and reinstalled it to sites/all/libraries from profiles/openatrium/libraries. Everything works fine again. I guess the problem was caused by downloading the colorbox library from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ instead of using the copy that was in the distribution.... Thanks again for your help that was pointing me in the right direction!